# Meteor 'submit' event not working, other events are working

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have following form HTML code :

```
<form class="login-form" method="post">
    <h3 class="form-title">Admin Login-20</h3>
    <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
        <span>
        Enter username and/or password. </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that-->
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Username</label>
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"/> Remember me </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn green pull-right">
            Login <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="forget-password">
        <p><a href="javascript:;" id="forget-password">Forgot Password</a></p>
    </div>

</form>
```

Following is event code :

```
    Template.adminLogin.events({

    "click form.login-form button[type='submit']": function (event, template) {

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Click button Login Form -01');
    },

    "keyup form.login-form": function(event, template){
         if(event.keyCode === 13) {
             event.preventDefault();
             console.log('Keyup Login Form - 01');
         }

    },

    "submit form.login-form": function (event, template) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
        console.log('Submit Login Form -01');

    }


});
```

My problem is 'click' , 'keyup' is working but 'submit'  is not working. Can some one guide me what is wrong and how it can be rectified.

Comment: (1) `event.preventDefault()` on the button click is preventing the final `submit` event. (2) Your `submit` event handler is returning `false` before the `console.log` can run. Unless you have more than one form in the template, you should just need a single `submit` event with no form name specifier (i.e. you don't need all these events anyway).

Answer (score 0):

One reason the console.log isn't working is that you are returning false before the console.log has a chance of running.

Moreover, you don't have to specify that the form method "post" like you would in php for instance. Typically you would just use javascript to grab the needed input values in the submit event and call some sort of method (like accounts.loginWithPassword for example). Also, the submit event takes care of the keyup and click event so those are redundant.

Sorry for any mistakes, im writing on mobile